# What is GeneratedEvaluationClass?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reflection, lambda, stream

I need to get a list of fields that are heirs of one class. These fields are private. But it does not matter, just need a list of these fields.

I have:

```
List<Field> linkFields = Arrays.stream(type.getDeclaredFields())
      .filter(field -> field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Link.class))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

as result (in debug mode by InteliJ Idea):

```
symbol:   method GeneratedEvaluationClass(java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends E>)
```

If I clear the filter, everything works out clean.

```
List<Field> linkFields = Arrays.stream(type.getDeclaredFields())
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

as result:

```
ArrayList<Field>
```

What does it mean?

Comment: I found my mistake. It is necessary to use getPath() instead of getClass(). But this did not solve the debugging problem. When debugging filtering in Intelij, an error occurs.

Comment: I suppose, you mean `getType()`, not `getPath()`. Besides that, it’s not clear which “debugging problem” you have. The result of your operation is a `List<Field>`, so what is that other “result” you have posted, which clearly describes some kind of method?